# how to have multiple @JoinColumns with existing column names

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I would like to make use of cascading while saving entities

my table A has col1 and col2 , and i would like to map these columns to multiple tables with different column names as coltable1 , coltable2 and so on

right now i am using

```
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="col1", referencedColumnName="col1table1"),
@JoinColumn(name="col2", referencedColumnName="col2table1")
})
table1 tble1;

@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="col1", referencedColumnName="col1table3"),
@JoinColumn(name="col2", referencedColumnName="col2table3")
})
table3 tble3;
```

but I am getting repeated columns in mapping for entity" error

I know I can use insertable and updatable as false but since I have to insert records it's irrelevant

can anyone help?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: taskRequest column: PROJECT_SEQ_NUM_I (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false") at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:830)
```

Comment: share the error you are getting

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: taskRequest column: PROJECT_SEQ_NUM_I (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")               at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:830)

Comment: the column mentioned in the exception not in the mapping you posted in the code.

Comment: The error tells you what to do! It isn't irrelevant at all and marking one set as read only does not prevent you from inserting records

Answer (score 2):

You have two mappings (tble1 and tble3) both using the same set of foreign keys in the current table. What do you think or want to happen if you create an instance that references a particular table1 instance but leave the tble3 reference as null? What values get into the database for those fk columns - do you want them left null or set to what ever values are in the col1table1/col2table1 values? JPA does not allow you to have multiple writable mappings to the same column and is requiring you to tell it how to handle things if they are not consistent

Pick one and mark the other as read-only by changing the join columns to be insertable=false, updatable=false:

```
@JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name="col1", referencedColumnName="col1table3", insertable=false, updatable=false),
  @JoinColumn(name="col2", referencedColumnName="col2table3", insertable=false, updatable=false)
})
table3 tble3;
```